# Unknown error when trying to archive for publishing Xamarin.Forms.iOS

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am currently releasing an update for an app and i can successfully debug the project. Now when i try to archive for publishing to create the .ipa file I recieve the following error:

[image]

I have tried to delete the obj + bin folders in my iOS folder and then clean/rebuild + try again but the error still remains.

Has anyone come across this problem before? The errormessage isn't giving me much information to work with.

Comment: Turn on diagnostic level logging for MSBuild and review the log for details concerning the error.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete your current certificate in keychain and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced to this same exact problem when I'm going to debug the xamarin.iOS app using Visual Studio 2015. To solve this issue, steps are as below,

1. Open Terminal in your Mac and type this command:

   ***security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s /Users                                                                   /YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db***
2. Then it will prompt for your Keychain access password. 
   (If it repeatedly promopt that your keychain access password is incorrect, go to "Keychain Access", select and deselect the lock. Then enter your password when asked for it.
3. Re-enter the above command in the Terminal. Give the password.
4. Clean and build your project and Run it.

Now it will work definetly.